# Sigmoid function in logistic regression

Tags: logistic

Normally I used $g(z)= \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$ as the sigmoid function, what is the difference when modify it to $g(z) = \frac{e^{-z}}{1+e^{-z}}$? Both are using the binary cross entropy loss to train the model.

For the logistic regression model $h() = {({^} )}$, and modify the original sigmoid function to  $g(z) = \frac{e^{-z}}{1+e^{-z}}$. I have never seen the new sigmoid function, so I would like to know the model prediction rule, and the learnt model parameters  differ from the conventional logistic regression.

Comment: Are you sure that you mean $\frac{e^{-z}}{1+e^{-z}}$ and not $\frac{e^{z}}{1+e^{z}}$??

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Yes, this is what I got.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've made an error in your question.  The function

$$ f(x) = \dfrac{\exp(x)}{1+\exp(x)}$$

is equivalent to the logistic function (divide top and bottom by $\exp(x)$ which is always positive).

$$ f(x) = \dfrac{\exp(x)}{1+\exp(x)} \dfrac{\frac{1}{\exp(x)}}{\frac{1}{\exp(x)}} = \dfrac{1}{\exp(-x) + 1} \equiv g(x) $$

I've plotted $f(x)$ in the black line and $g(x)$ in the black dots below.  The function you've written is in red below.  The red function is not equal to the sigmoid.

[image]

Comment: I have edited the question, and see whether you can understand?

Comment: @janiceckm Your $g(z)$ has not changed.  It is still my red curve.